# Find evey open MS Access instance/file

Tags: vb.net, vba, ms-access

I've had an ongoing neglected question on Expert's Exchange that I would love to finally have answered.  Here's the link:

[My Expert's Exchange question](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Visual_Basic.NET/Q_28425418.html)

My objective is to return a list of every Access file that the user has open at any one time.  The site includes a complete set of code to retrieve all open Excel and Word files as an array of those application objects.  I've tried everything I know to solve this problem and am poised to pay Microsoft Tech Support to help me answer this question, if no one on the forums is forthcoming with an answer.

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: @MikeCheel: The question is in the title

Comment: I thought the code in your link accomplished it.

Comment: I quickly glanced at the code and it appeared they were on the right path. May I ask what you are trying to accomplish and also you can search windows by text (using winapi). It seems to me (at least in Office 2007 which is what I have access to) each document open whether it is access, excel or word, has a pattern like 'My file - Microsoft Access | Word | Excel'. You could potentially loop through the titles of the windows and look for those patterns. If you plan on going the winapi route spy++ will be your friend.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions you link for Excel and Word function by looking for instances of those programs running, and using their known COM interface to find the files they have open.

With Access, other things can open the files as well.  For example, a C# program or SQL Server import wizard could also have the files open.

A general solution would be rather tricky.  However, if you can be sure that the files have the [usual extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Office_filename_extensions#Access), you could enumerate all files that are open in the system and return a list of those that have an appropriate file extension.

To enumerate all open files in the system, see the EnumerateOpenedFiles() method in this article

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/OpenedFileFinder.aspx?fid=422864&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=26&select=2277170

Note that you don't need all of the code there, as it presents a shell extension that calls EnumerateOpenedFiles() as part of it's operation.  You only need that one method, modified to return only files matching the desired file extensions.

Comment: I downloaded the source code from the site mentioned, but I think there's a problem.  I have Visual Studio 2010, which includes Visual Basic, C3, C++, and F#, but not C.  I'll try one of these, if you think it will work.  I ran the executable code, and it looked interesting, but not quite that for which I was looking.  In the Excel listings, for example, it appeared to contain a comprehensive list of all the files that Excel references for its code, but not the file that was open.  Still, I think you're on the right track, and this may lead to that for which I'm looking.  Thanks, ~Peter

Comment: @user3621522: You don't need to compile anything in C.  Just copy the code for EnumerateOpenedFiles() to your own project.

Comment: OK, this time, I copied and pasted the enumerate function directly into my C# code module, and it gave me an error on nearly every line.  Having the code is not enough: I must also have a compiler that recognizes the language in which the code is written.  Absent that, I have not really made any progress.  If there's something that's written in C# or Visual Basic that does the same thing, this would be of greater use to me.  Expecially Visual Basic, with which I have a great deal of experience and skill.  Thanks!  ~Peter Ferber